# Is there any possible way I can prompt the user to select a timezone just like in plain Ubuntu in a customized ISO?

Tags: 14.04, server, timezone, kickstart

Currently I provide a modified ISO to users and it has many configurations in ks.cfg for configuration post installation of OS. The users are in different timezones. Till now there is no manual intervention required for installation. But now I just want to prompt the user to select a timezone(like in vanilla Ubuntu) during installation so that the services that start with post installation can sync in, according to the user selected timezone. Since I think using a ks.cfg file eliminates user intervention totally.

Comment: Why not do that after the install on 1st login? Put a file somewhere. have it execute on boot and on success remove it.

Comment: But the script should:
1) Execute during boot, before other services start.
2) Should prompt the user with timezones available in Linux, and let's him select depending on his location.

Comment: Regarding 1: Why? Here is a set of classical methods. from command line to using the desktop: https://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Timezone-in-Linux    Changing timezone can be done in real time on a running system. No need for a reboot.

Comment: My main issue is the script "should start before other services". Since my services need to be sync with the system TimeZone. If the TimeZone changes on real time, the services would need to be restarted. And I don't want to do unnecessary restart of my services.